# Statements works in SQL, but not in PDO

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm converting from SQL to PDO, and everything has gone well until this statement.

My SQL does what it should and does NOT output the message *"This user has no private images"*. But for some reason, when changing to PDO, the same message is shown when it should not be.

Any ideas?

**Original SQL:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_private_photos WHERE profile = $usernum AND photo_deleted != 'Yes' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)!==1) { die("This user has no private images");}
```

**My PDO:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_private_photos WHERE profile = :usernum AND photo_deleted != 'Yes' LIMIT 1";

        $q   = $conn->prepare($sql); // the default way of PDO to manage errors is quite the same as `or die()` so no need for that
        $q->bindValue(':usernum',$usernum,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $q->execute();

            if($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)!==1)
            {
                die("This user has no private images");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDO::fetch()`  returns in this case an `array` or `false`.  You don't want to compare the fetch result explicitly to the integer 1 then assign it to a variable--it will always be `true` because a `1 !== array()` is always true, and `1 !== false` is always true.

Instead you should  see if your result set is empty or `false`.

Try this instead:

```
 $r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if(empty($r))
 {
    die("This user has no private images");
 }
```

Comment: Surely it would still work though because I have used 'LIMIT 1' to ensure it would work. Whether there is 1 or 10 results, it should stick at 1

Comment: @ElaineAdams !== is a hard comparison to the integer 1, no casting or anything like that.  'fetch' does not return an integer.  Then you're assigning it to $r, that will probably always eval to `true` in your if